# Complex power series convergence test.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

So I have tried solving the following, seemingly simple, power series. ***The solution should be that the series diverges***, but I do not see how I would go about testing for convergence/divergence apart from a root test, which wouldn't help either by the looks of things (is this a false assumption?).

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (\frac{1+2i}{\sqrt{5}}  \right )^{n }
$$

With ratio test:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left |\left (\frac{1+2i}{\sqrt{5}}  \right )^{n+1}\left (\frac{\sqrt{5}}{1+2i}  \right )^{n} \right |=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left |   \frac{1+2i}{\sqrt{5}}   \right | = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left | 1+2i \right |= \frac {\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}}=1
$$

Which is inconclusive. From here on I do not see any alternative apart from the root test, which looks like it shouldn't help.

Best regards,
Raoul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the absolute value of n'th term? Check it. You might be surprised.

Comment: You might just as well start writing \to instead of \rightarrow. Also, why $5^n$ in the numerator? Is $|1+2i|=5$? Also, I didn't say a word about limit; just the n'th term.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Ivan.

I've noticed that I've made some unnecessary mistakes while concentrating on LaTeX..

Comment: To look at the n'th term, do I not need to use limits to approximate it?

Comment: No; why? Why approximate when you have the exact formula for it: $a_n=\left(1+2i\over\sqrt5\right)^n$. Now, what is the absolute value?

Comment: Ah yes. Do you mean as follows:
$$
\left |  a_{n}  \right |= \frac {\left |  \left( 1+2i \right)^{n}  \right |}{\sqrt{5}^{n}} 
$$
And since $ \left( 1+2i \right)^{n} \to \infty, \left| a_{n}\right| \to \infty $

I apologise, but I find series in general quite difficult.

Comment: Not really. True, $|(1+2i)^{n}| \to \infty$, but so does $(\sqrt5)^n$. Can't we simplify it?

Comment: Ah, since the n'th term is equal to one, the sum will diverge. The nth term should be less than one to converge, is that correct?

Comment: Not the n'th term, but its absolute value. Also, it it not enough for it just to be less than 1; it should tend to 0 (which it doesn't). Other than that, you are right.